# Write R in Roster Form

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $R=\{\langle x,y\rangle \mid x \in X \wedge y \in X \wedge (x-y)$ is an integral non-zero multiple of $2\}$. My textbook's answer is $R=\{\langle 1,3\rangle, \langle 2,4\rangle\}$ why it does not include $\langle3,1\rangle, \langle4,2\rangle$? Please can anybody explain?

Comment: The way you described it, it should.

Comment: @Steven is correct; your textbook’s answer is wrong, and yours is correct.

Comment: I think so..< > doesn't it mean for absolute value..if it so then my textbook is right..but for absolute value vertical lines are used | |

Comment: The use of angle brackets instead of normal brackets in the set-builder form of $R$ suggests that they might be defining $R$ to contain unordered pairs? That would mean $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle y,x\rangle$.

Comment: which text book you are using ? 
In the book "Discrete Mathematical Structures with Application to Computer Science", having same example with answer of R={⟨1,3⟩,⟨2,4⟩, (3,1), (4,2)}. And obviously its a correct answer.

Comment: thanks for comment

Comment: Is the expression, $\langle x,y\rangle$ an _ordered_ tuple? If not, then the proposed additional solutions are just alternate representations of the given solutions.

Comment: I am using Discrete Mathematics-I by D.R sharma

Comment: @justin Benfield yes sir it seems to be unorder pair..then my textbook is right?

Comment: Yes, the pair $\langle 1,3\rangle=\langle 3,1\rangle$ so there are only two _unordered_ pairs in $R$.

Comment: I should add, that it's odd for the author not to just use set notation, e.g. $\{ 1,3\}$ for this

Comment: @justin Benfield thanks sir